# Registrar pulsación de f1

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Estoy en la busqueda de un comando que reconozca la pulsación de lcontrol o lo que yo le indique. intenté algo similar, el problema es que tengo que utilizarlo con la terminal abierta y así no me funciona

```
read -p  'Press A to continue...   ' key
echo "T: $key"
if [ "$key" = 'a' ]; then

        eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
        echo "Está es la posición: $X $Y"



else
        echo "Tecla incorrecta"

fi
```

Lo que quiero lograr hacer es un Script que esté en un bucle infinito y sin necesidad de yo tener la terminal abierta poder presionar F1 y que se ejecute las lineas para obtener la posición del mouse

Comment: ¿Estás intentando detectarlo en algún mommento concreto de un script? Puedes añadir un poco más de contexto a tus requerimientos, por favor?

Comment: Estaba pensando en meter ese script en un bucle infinito y cuando presione f1 obtener la posicion del mouse

Comment: lo que quieres es que detecte que una tecla fue pulsada?

Comment: @Simon Exacto, Ejemplo: al pulsar control izquierdo obtener posición del mouse

Answer (score 1):

```
read -rsn1
```

Usando el comando read read-in
El comando integrado de lectura es la contraparte de los comandos echo y printf.
[info](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html)

puedes crear algo asi:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
read -rsn1 input
if [ "$input" = "a" ]; then
    echo "hello world"
fi
done
```

y cuando yo presione la letra `a` me muestra el hello world

**¿Cómo puedo ejecutar un script de shell en segundo plano?**

Dependiendo de lo que quieras, simplemente agrega un & al final del comando

```
script.sh &
command &
```

Si lo está ejecutando en una terminal y quiere cerrar la terminal, use nohup o reniegue

nohup

```
nohup script.sh &
```

disown

```
    script &
    disown
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar, pero el script que quiero es poder presionar f1 sin tener la terminal abierta, y ese que me pasaste tengo que tener la terminal abierta y presionar a, de todas formas ese script que hiciste me gustó y lo guardaré

Comment: quieres que se ejecute en segundo plano? ahh te fueras explicado asi,ahi edito el codigo

Comment: yo edite anoche y lo acomodé, lee ahora

Comment: @Kiyosaki listo agregado.

Comment: Al ejecutar el script con & al final me devuelve [5] 1098 ¿qué significa?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

while true; do 
  read -sn3 key
  if [ "$key" = "$(tput kf1)" ];  then
    echo "HOla"
  else
    echo "- > $key fue presionada"
  fi
done


sólo me funciona con la terminal maximizada, si la tengo minimizada no ejecuta, ese es el problema

Comment: deberias crear un proceso en segundo plano, esta pregunta se relacionas sobre eso: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276020/how-do-i-start-a-background-process-from-a-shell-script-and-log-the-output-of-th